# <bpmndi:BPMNShape> Is Missing for participant and lane element in xml when trying to create pool and lane from java source

Tags: java, jaxb, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

Here is the code snippet I am writing to generate simple **.bpmn** file

```
public void testDynamicDeploy() throws Exception {
      BpmnModel model = new BpmnModel();
      Process process = new Process();

      model.addProcess(process);
      process.setId("process");

      process.addFlowElement(createStartEvent());
      process.addFlowElement(createUserTask("task1", "First task", "fred"));
      process.addFlowElement(createUserTask("task2", "Second task", "john"));
      process.addFlowElement(createEndEvent());

      process.addFlowElement(createSequenceFlow("start", "task1"));
      process.addFlowElement(createSequenceFlow("task1", "task2"));
      process.addFlowElement(createSequenceFlow("task2", "end"));

      Pool newPool = ActivitiElements.createPool("LMS", "LMS1");
      newPool.setProcessRef(process.getId());

    Lane lane = ActivitiElements.createLane("Booking1", "Booking");
    lane.getFlowReferences().add("start");
    lane.getFlowReferences().add("task1");
    lane.getFlowReferences().add("task3");
    lane.getFlowReferences().add("end");
    lane.setParentProcess(process);

     process.getLanes().add(lane);

    model.getPools().add(newPool);

   new BpmnAutoLayout(model).execute();

   byte[] xml = new BpmnXMLConverter().convertToXML(model);
   FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(targetFile, xml);
}
```

The generated targetFile file is missing **"bpmndi:BPMNShape"** element for

```
<participant id="LMS" name="LMS1" processRef="process"></participant>
```

and

```
<lane id="Booking1" name="Booking">
```

I checked **model.getLocationMap()** it contains all *FlowElement* **GraphicInfo** except participant and lane.

Please help to solve this issue

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible with **BpmnXMLConverter().convertToXML(model);**

https://community.alfresco.com/thread/231380-bpmndibpmnshape-is-missing-for-participant-and-lane-element-in-xml-when-trying-to-create-pool-and-lane-from-java-source